# Shared Element Listener

Tags: android, android-studio, fadein, shared-element-transition

Is I have defined a shared element animation (Going from Activity A to Activity B) using the following line of code (have defined appropriate values in my xml files - belive):

```
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, (View)sharedElement, "transitionName");
```

My question is, once this shared element is animated on Activity B, is there some sort of on finish listener for this shared element animation? I am asking this because I want to code a fade in animation for the rest of the content in Activity B, but want the fade in to occur only after the shared element animation has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can even change duration, add more transitions ...

To do in `onCreate` of Activity B:

```
Window window = getWindow();
TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
set.addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
set.setDuration(duration);
set.addListener(yourTransitionListener);
window.setSharedElementEnterTransition(set);
```